# Failed to resolve library only on one project but not on others

Tags: android, android-studio, github

I have been using this library for a 3-app project

`'com.github.therealshabi:AutoImageFlipper:1.5.8'`

After using it for about a week now in app 1, I tried to include it in app 2 as well, but got this error `ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.github.therealshabi:AutoImageFlipper:1.5.8`

Confused, I tried to include it in app 3, and it worked just fine (it wasn't included in app 3 before).

I've tried to invalidate caches and restart but that didn't help. What could be wrong? Why would it happen only on one project and not on others, if it's the same library?

Comment: Can you post the whole build.gradle please.

Comment: @jake your comment made me realize what was wrong. I've added the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Beginner's mistake. What I forgot to include is `mavenCentral()` under `all projects` in the project level gradle. After I've added that it works.

Answer (score 0):

add 
maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
in allprojects